# Mysql Fetch Records Based on Multiple Cases

Tags: mysql, database

I do have merchant_credit_history table where I am storing merchant credit,debit and transaction type.

I want to SUM of CREDIT or DEBIT based on transaction type.

**Records**

[image]

I Tried this :

SELECT  SUM(ABS(debit)) as **dealer_credit**
FROM merchant_credits_history
WHERE transaction_type='premium_debit' and merchant_id='x'

UNION

SELECT SUM(ABS(credit)) as **dealer_margin_earned**
FROM merchant_credits_history
WHERE transaction_type='margin_credit' and merchant_id='x'

**and getting the out put as**

[image]

I would appreciate if I can have better query and also the values in separate key value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE(WHEN transaction_type='premium_debit') THEN debit ELSE 0)) as dealer_credit, 
    SUM(CASE(WHEN transaction_type='margin_credit') THEN credit ELSE 0)) as dealer_margin_earned 
    FROM merchant_credits_history 
    WHERE merchant_id='x';
```

Thus you get a pair of credit, debit values for each merchant_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Debit), SUM(CREDIT) FROM 
   (SELECT 
      CASE WHEN transaction_type='premium_debit' THEN debit ELSE 0 END as Debit, 
      CASE WHEN transaction_type='margin_credit' THEN credit ELSE 0 END as Credit
   FROM Customers WHERE merchant_id='x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT SUM(ABS(credit)) as Credit, SUM(ABS(debit)) AS Debit, 
transaction_type FROM merchant_credits_history merchant_id='x'
GROUP BY (transaction_type);
```